# StringListProperty in GAE/J

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there StringListProperty just in Python or in Java too? I cant find it in the Java API.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one by having

```
@Persistent
List<String> favoriteFoods;
```

Details can be found at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear that I don't want to use JPA or JDO but the low-level-API. But I try a setPrperty(name, list-of-strings) then.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html),

```
The type of a field can be any of the following...
   ...
a Collection (such as a java.util.List<...>) or an array of values of a core datastore type
```

so a `List<String>` should just work.